# how do we block the UI by grayout screen?

Tags: java, android

When the user clicks on submit button it will do some background processing, mean while how do we block the UI by showing progress with the grayout the screen ?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.41post.com/4588/programming/android-coding-a-loading-screen-part-1), it has some great information that will help you achieve what you are after.
*Hint:* make the dialog used in the article to show the progress full screen to cover all your application screen estate